# Keras and make_csv_dataset compatibility

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Can tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset() be used for Keras models in tensorflow 1.9.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset() returns a tf.data.Dataset and you can pass tf.data.Dataset to the fit method of Keras models.
See some examples here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets